# How to solve java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no NBioBSPJNI in java.library.path

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am getting this error after adding the native library also.even i also tried to add my file to java class path but again i am getting the same error .
will any one please tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The UnsatisfiedLinkError denotes that the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared as native.

The UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown when an application attempts to load a native library like .so in Linux, .dll on Windows and that library does not exist. Specifically, in order to find the required native library, the JVM looks in both the PATH environment variable and the java.library.path system property.

**How to deal with the UnsatisfiedLinkError**

check NBioBSPJNI.so present in **java.library.path** or in the **PATH** environment library of your application.